# how to prevent Junit in eclipse from pop up?

Tags: eclipse, junit

how could I prevent from Junit view to pop up  every time I running a test?

Answer (score 3):

The Junit view always needs to be there when you run junit. To stop it popping up dock it with another view - I tend to have it docked with the console and switch between these views using the tabs.